# PHP Session, allowing login to other files

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have 2 PHP Login files. They have different logins and should display different HTML when logged in. There is index.php for main login, and admin.php for admin login. If a user logs into index.php, and then they go to admin.php they automatically get logged into admin.
Could it be an issue with the code saving the same session for each file? And how would I fix this?
Thanks!

Below code is the same for index.php and admin.php however, changed the HTML and logins.

EDIT: Resolved Issue by changing session vars. Thanks!

````php
<?php
        session_start();
        $userinfo = array(
            'user'=>'5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592', //Hello...
        );

        if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = '';
            header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
            if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == md5($_POST['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            }else {
                header("location:403.html"); //replace with 403
            }
        }
?>
<?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Logged In</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <p>You're logged in.</p>
            <a href="logout.php">LOG OUT</a>
        </body>
    </html>

<?php else: ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Log In</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Login needed</h1>
            <form name="login" action="" method="post">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><strong>System Login</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="78">Username:</td>
                        <td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php endif; ?>```
````

Comment: So how do you distinguish between a standard user and an Admin user ???

Comment: he obviously has an array with the username as key and password as the value

Comment: Obviously you need to use a different SESSION variable for Users and Admins

Comment: @RiggsFolly User and Admin logins are different php files, but the same code.

Comment: Sorry new to php. So to change the session var, for example right now its `$_SESSION['username']`, I could change to `$_SESSION['adminusername']`?
@RiggsFolly

Comment: William, yes thats the basic idea

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit after the headers

```
        if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
            if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == md5($_POST['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            }else {
                header("location:403.html"); //replace with 403
                exit;
            }
        }
```

If you don't exit the script can continue processing and display the html, once the html is displayed the header will fail.

Comment: Actually the header will get actioned and you wont see anything that would have been sent to the old page even though all the remaining code is executed

Comment: not always .. you must exit after headers or you will see unexpected results